# index out of bounds when accessing last item in array

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have a random number generator feeding numbers into an array, but when I print out the table, the last line is always a set of values out of the boundaries that I defined in the following function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int temp[22];
    int n;
    for(n=0; n<23; n++){
        temp[n] = rand()%(100 + 1 - 60) + 60;
        printf("%d  ,  %d \n", n, temp[n]);
}
return 0;
```

Ive created something of this nature before, but now its acting up, I just dont know where.

Comment: `for(n=0; n<23; n++)` -> `for(n=0; n<22; n++)`

Comment: Funny. The last iteration probably overwrites `n` in the 1st statement, and then the access of `temp[n]` in the next line accesses some random location (UB).

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I'm sorry, Is there something you could not understand about my question? I appreciate the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is being accessed outside of its bounds.

```
int temp[22];
```

> This declaration assigns 22 indices to temp, `temp[0]` is the first
>   value and `temp[21]` is the last value you can access in your array. Counting 0, from 0..21 = we have **22 values**

---

Your for loop is incorrect:

```
for(n=0; n<23; n++)
```

This will make the program attempt to access `temp[22]`, which doesn't exist. You need to change it to:

```
for(n=0; n<22; n++)
```

> **Furthermore**:
>   `return 0;` needs to be inside and at the end of your main() function. It's possibly a typo, but you're missing a closing brace `}` in your `main()` function, at least how you posted it.

Comment: not the dv, but "return 0; needs to be inside and at the end of your main() function," is not strictly true.

Comment: @George it's not necessary, but as it currently stands, there's global **return 0** there, which is incorrect. The main function isn't being closed.

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing the array outside the bounds which is *undefined behaviour*.

Instead make use of `sizeof` operator to avoid such problems:

```
for(n = 0; n < sizeof temp/sizeof temp[0]; n++)
```

But note that if `temp` were to be an malloc'ed pointer (`int *temp = malloc(23 * sizeof *temp);`) then `sizeof` wouldn't work.